# argparse: how to get all arguments after specific key?

Tags: python, argparse

for example:

```sh
python foo.py --foo foo --bar bar --args -a 5 --baz 6
```

`--foo` and `--bar` are regular arguments, but `--args` is special, it should contain list of args after it: `[-a, 5, --baz, 6]`.

I remember that something similar exists but I cannot remember how it is called.

Comment: Are you thinking of `parse_known_args()`? See https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#partial-parsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `argparse.REMAINDER`:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo')
parser.add_argument('--bar')
parser.add_argument('--args', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)

print(parser.parse_args())
```

When running `python foo.py --foo foo --bar bar --args -a 5 --baz 6` this returns:

```
Namespace(args=['-a', '5', '--baz', '6'], bar='bar', foo='foo')
```